# Magento 2: Product Tab Enabled only get collection using layout xml

Tags: layout, magento-2.0, magento-2.1

Below my code for xml. I create product tab like below code for product-details page.
**Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
                <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Test" name="test.product" as="deliveryinfo" template="Vendor_Module::product/producttest.phtml" group="detailed_info" ifconfig="vendor_module/general/product_test">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Product Test</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Below Screenshot is product-page.
[image]
Now i try, if collection get Product Test Tab is Enabled and collection get is zero(empty) Product Test Tab is disabled.
How it posible using layout xml code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way to this using the layout. However, if you need to hide a tab when a collection is empty, you can simply add a check at the beginning of your tab's template (.phtml). Here is the example:

```
<?php
$collectionSize = null; // your code here
if (!$collectionSize) {
    return;
}
?>
<!-- html here -->
```

In this example if the size of collection will be 0, then the template won't be drawn and you will see nothing on a product's page:

[image]

Alternatively, the tab should be drawn normally:

[image]